# Ubuntu 20.04 Python 3.10 pip import error

Tags: 20.04, python, python3

I've recently install python 3.10 in my ubuntu 20.04. My steps for installation were:

```
apt install python3.10
apt install python3.10-dev
apt install python3.10-distutils
```

Problem is about the `pip`. It crashes when I try to install anything with error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'html5lib' from 'pip._vendor' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py)
```

I have python versions **3.6 - 3.9** installed on my system. This problem only occurs with python version `3.10`. What's the cause of this problem and solution?

Answer (score 4):

The following commands solved my `pip` and `sudo pip` problems:

```bash
curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.10
```

```bash
curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python3.10
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved exactly the same symptoms by entering pipenv shell and installing pip there:

```
pipenv shell
curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

This resulted in:

```
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-21.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.0.2
    Uninstalling pip-20.0.2:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-20.0.2
Successfully installed pip-21.3.1
```

After that things started to work as expected and `pipenv install` was successful. Countless other ways of installing and reinstalling python/pip/pipenv failed, many times with the same import error.

Comment: right now `pip install` is working for me. I don't know how this issue is disappeared on its own.

Answer (score -1):

You should better use pyenv and/or virtualenv. Some libs are not compatible with different python versions. Also pip does not know for what python version you want to install the requested lib.

Here are some tutorials or go and search in youtube.

https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/
https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: but this error also happens inside my `pipenv` environment. `pipenv install somepackage` also results in import error

Comment: You probably can sort out this error after watch this pipenv course. https://youtu.be/6Qmnh5C4Pmo